# Removing italic formatting from if statement

Tags: fonts, algorithm2e, italic

I would like the if statement to have "current stage" in serif and "satisfies" as normal text. The following code produces both with italics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}

\If{\textsf{current\_state} \textrm{satisfies} \textsf{goal}}
{
return \textsf{existing\_plan}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With both of the solutions below, I would *strongly* recommend abstracting these concepts into new commands, e.g. `\Var{current-state} \Satisfies \Var{goal}`.  If you use `xparse` and a *tiny* bit of `expl3`, you can auto-replace `-` to `_`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `algorithm2e` package uses `\ArgSty` to typeset the argument of `\If`. If you don't want italics, add

```
\SetArgSty{textup}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetArgSty{textup}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\If{\textsf{current\_state} satisfies \textsf{goal}}
{
return \textsf{existing\_plan}
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\textup` instead of `\textrm` as suggested by egreg. The code now reads like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}

\If{\textsf{current\_state} \textup{satisfies} \textsf{goal}}
{
return \textsf{existing\_plan}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and the output as required:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't mark yours as the answer too because it's definitely correct. I went for the other because it was visually exactly the effect I was after. I gave an upvote as compensation. Thanks for your help!